# ipvsadm output processing

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, gawk

I need to process ipvsadm output which is similiar to this:

```
IP Virtual Server version 0.2.12 (size=16384)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port             Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  lvs2.mack.net:0 rr persistent 360
  -> RS2.mack.net:0                 Route   1      0          0
  -> RS1.mack.net:0                 Route   1      0          0
  -> RS3.mack.net:0                 Route   1      0          0
TCP  lvs2.mack.net:https rr
  -> RS2.mack.net:https            Route   1      0          0
TCP  lvs2.mack.net:telnet rr
  -> RS2.mack.net:telnet            Route   1      0          0
  -> RS1.mack.net:telnet            Route   1      0          0
TCP  lvs2.mack.net:ssh rr
TCP  lvs2.mack.net:hvr rr
```

and on output I expect only these VIPs which have less than 2 real nodes 'alive' at the moment. So processing of example data above, expected output is:

```
TCP  lvs2.mack.net:https rr
  -> RS2.mack.net:https            Route   1      0          0
TCP  lvs2.mack.net:ssh rr
TCP  lvs2.mack.net:hvr rr
```

because as we see one VIP has only 1 real node active and the other two none avaialble.

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR<4{ next }
     /TCP/{ if (host && c<2) printf "%s%s\n",host,(c==1? ORS node:""); host=$0; c=0 }
     host && $1=="->"{ node=$0; c++ }
     END{ if (host && c<2) print host }' file
```

- `NR<4{ next }` - skip the first 3 lines (`NR` indicates total number of rows been read)
- `/TCP/` - on encountering *host* line started with `TCP`:

  - `host=$0` - capture the whole line into variable `host`
  - `c=0` - count for number of nodes for the current *host*
  - `if (host && c<2) printf "%s%s\n",host,(c==1? ORS node:"")` - if there's a previously processed host and the number of its nodes is `c<2` - print the host line and its node(if exists)
- `host && $1=="->"{ node=$0; c++ }` - for the currently processed *host* - capture its *node* line into variable `node` and incrementing the number of nodes `c++`
- `END{ if (host && c<2) print host }` - check for remaining host that has been processed but not printed

---

The output:

```
TCP  lvs2.mack.net:https rr
  -> RS2.mack.net:https            Route   1      0          0
TCP  lvs2.mack.net:ssh rr
TCP  lvs2.mack.net:hvr rr
```